# Dynamic HTML Page Title with PHP

Tags: php, html, dynamic, title

I have a website which uses a PHP content management system to add and edit articles (see example article: http://bournemotorclub.co.uk/latestnews.php?fn_mode=fullnews&fn_id=41 )

What I'd like to be able to do is to set the title of the HTML page (which at the moment, in the example above, is BMRC: Latest News) to the subject of the article (ie 'Review of 2013' in the example above)

Does anyone have any experience with doing this sort of thing, or have any advice as to the coding I need to use. I've tried using:

```
<title> <?php $news_info['subject'] ?> </title>
```

but that just left the title blank.

Any help given is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It happens to everyone... ;) `echo`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have all your connection details and other php files set up, all you would need to do is this:

```
<title> <?php echo $news_info['subject'] ?> </title>
```

Comment: Well no, everyone knows shorthand. Nothing to copy. The original answer was valid, i just added this in to offer separate options.

Comment: better not to use shorthand (which is actually short tags not shorthand) in all cases :)

Comment: Think i will remove the short tag idea. Forgot about xml header issues/not supported etc

Comment: Also, @RajMohan i could understand your point if i completely ripped your answer, however i answered first with the current answer and i don't appreciate the downvote on this answer based on the fact i added short tags.

Comment: @RajMohan i removed it because of the above comment ^ regarding short tags. Nothing to do with your answer dude, let it go.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **echo**:

```
<title> <?php echo $news_info['subject'] ?> </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing echo:
Plz check the answer

```
<title> <?=$news_info['subject']?> </title>
```

Comment: Why was he down voted he did not give the same answer he used shorthand which is what most templates use anyway.